# Add data series content in another data series

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

Is there a way to concatenate the information of two data series in pandas? Not append or merge the information of two data frames, but actually combine the content of each data series in a new data series.

Example:

```
ColumnA (Item type) Row 2 = 1 (float64)
ColumnB (Item number) Row 2 = 1 (float64)
ColumnC (Registration Date) Row 2 = 04/07/2018 (43285) (datetime64[ns])
```

In excel I would concatenate the rows in Column `A`, `B`, `C` and have the number in each column combined, using the formula `=concat(A2, B2, C2)`
The result would be `1143285` in another cell `D2`, for example.

Is there a way for me to do that in Pandas? I could only find ways to join, combined or append the series in the data frame but not in the series itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use that

```
df['D'] = df.apply(lambda row : str(row['A'])+
                     str(row['B']) + str(row['C']), axis = 1)
```

Following your example it would be

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'A': [1],'B':[1],'C':[43285]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['D'] = df.apply(lambda row : str(row['A'])+
                     str(row['B']) + str(row['C']), axis = 1)
```

Output:

```
   A  B      C        D
0  1  1  43285  1143285
```